# How do you make an offset for putting things in an array while having it loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to make a code that sets the second array of characters to the second half of the first array of characters, but where I can change a number and it changes where each character is on the second array.

For instance if array 1 is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0] and the variable changing it is 3, then array 2 should be [9,0,6,7,8].

I have tried

```
for(var q = Math.floor(Charecter1.length/2); q<Charecter1.length;q++){
            var v = q + document.getElementById("seed").value
            for (var w = 0; v >= Charecter1.length; w++){
                v-=Math.ceil(Charecter1.length/2)
            }
            Charecter2[v - Math.floor(Charecter1.length/2)] = Charecter1[(-1*q)+(Charecter1.length-1)]
}
```

When it starts,

- Charecter1 is ["q","w","e","r","t","y","u","i","o","p","a","s","d","f","g","h","j","k","l",";",":","'",'"',"z","x","c","v","b","n","m",",","<",">","`","~","1","!","2","@","3","#","4","5","%","6","7","&","8","9","0","_","="," ","Q","W","E","R","T","Y","U","I","O","P","A","S","D","F","G","H","J","K","L","Z","X","C","V","B","N","M"]
- document.getElementById("seed").value is 0
- Charecter2 should be ["3","#","4","5","%","6","7","&","8","9","0","_","="," ","Q","W","E","R","T","Y","U","I","O","P","A","S","D","F","G","H","J","K","L","Z","X","C","V","B","N","M"]

but, when i run the code it says Charecter2 is [empty, "e", empty × 9, "w", empty × 9, "q", empty × 9, "r"]. I do not understand why this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a temporary array with the last half of the array and build from this array the last part first and the first part at last with the given offset.

This approach uses a bitwise shifting by one to the right. The result is an integer value, like

```
Math.floor(array.length / 2)
```

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
    offset = 3,
    temp = array.slice(array.length >> 1),
    result = [...temp.slice(offset), ...temp.slice(0, offset)];

console.log(result);
```